# Heisenberg theory of uncertainty

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, wavelength

I was watching a video on YouTube about uncertainty theory of Heisenberg it said that there is a relation between momentum (multiple of mass and speed) and wave length. And the relation is that if something has a big momentum (it can have a big mass like the meas of an electron or a big speed or either one), it has a short wavelength. 
What is this relation? Where does such an implication come from?

Comment: See [de Broglie wavelength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave). In a nutshell, $\lambda\propto 1/p$.

Comment: The Davisson-Germer experiment may be useful too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davisson%E2%80%93Germer_experiment

Comment: Please see [our guide](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles) on writing good titles.